# Is it valid to use a Blend d:Style.DataContext inside WPF resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

When defining WPF styles, I often use the Expression Blend `<d:Style.DataContext>` tag to let Intellisense know what the runtime DataContext will be.  It works great.  Unfortunately I cannot seem to make this work in a resource dictionary and I am unclear as to why.

For example, here in a style for a `RadTabItem`, I tell Intellisense that `SettingsPageVm` will be the DataContext:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.ConfigureView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:tk="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:ConfigureVm}">

    <Grid>
        <tk:RadTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" >  

            <tk:RadTabControl.Resources>

                <!-- Tell setters that SettingsPageVm will be the datacontext -->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:RadTabItem}">
                    <d:Style.DataContext>
                        <x:Type Type="viewModels:SettingsPageVm" />
                    </d:Style.DataContext>

                <!-- (Imagine many setters here, binding to SettingsPageVm) -->
```

This works fine.

But if try I move that same style to a separate ResourceDictionary Visual Studio complains.  The editor puts a blue squiggly underneath the `d:Style.DataContext` declaration and highlights it red.  The compiler complains about it as follows:

> 1>I:\Dev\MyApp\Resources\Styles\DialogStyles.xaml(13,14): error
>   MC4004: Style cannot contain child 'TypeExtension'. Style child must
>   be a Setter because it is added to the Setters collection. Line 13
>   Position 14.

Why is this valid in one context and not valid in another?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels"
                    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                    >
    <Style x:Key="SettingsPageTabStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type tk:RadTabItem}">
        <d:Style.DataContext>                           <!-- *** ERROR *** -->
            <x:Type Type="viewModels:SettingsPageVm" />
        </d:Style.DataContext>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question because half a day later I stumbled on it.

I had neglected to add the

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

line to my XAML.  Once I did that, everything worked fine.

(Just One of those obscure WPF lessons that I am sure I already learned and then forgot at least once before -- maybe twice -- in the past over several years of working on WPF.  )

Comment: still tanks for your solution. Sometimes it's hard to see trees inside a forest...